# C# LastIndexOf not giving correct result

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

in this particular line of code :

```
correct = Array.LastIndexOf(turns.ToArray(), false, 4, 0);
```

I get result `correct = -1`, well how is this even possible ?

`turns[0]` up to `turns[3]` are equal to `false` `turns[4]=true` and `turns[5]=false` is it possible to be caused because the last index i want to be looked up to is 4 and it has value different than the required one ?

Comment: try changing last argument to > 0

Comment: Yea it did the job thanks for the quick responses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with the last argument (count). This restricts the number of elements searched. You are restricting it to search 0 elements starting at index 4. Thus, it doesn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
correct = Array.LastIndexOf(turns.ToArray(), false, turns.Length, turns.Length);
```

What were you doing wrong:

- never hard code array length (especially in your case, when the array is filled with values)
- the first index is actually the starting search index from **backwards**, and the second index is actually the count, i.e. how many items to search ([MSDN constructor clarification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8s39by5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

**Update 1:**

Made a mistake on the starting index and the count number. Updated the changes, thank you @Steve for pointing it out.

Comment: From MSDN: _StartIndex = The starting index of the **backward** search_

Answer (score 0):

Your count indicates searching 0 elements in the section.

```
correct = Array.LastIndexOf(turns.ToArray(), false, 4, 2);
```